# Why the Loop not properly Looping through the data?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

```php
<?php
$id = array(
    "UC4MubF2asPHQbXN44DVNeXg",
    "UCXuDgoo_oiZf8UkIXs3Y_kw",
    "UCMnDuOzzJrWzr5tfemDcqlQ",
    "UC9FH1mkHLFQuPPEPu9CfR1A",
    "UCfyEAw41i7PRetP2erYf9dg",
);

// Getting Emails from DB and Looping with Channel Title and Video Title

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$query = "SELECT * FROM prospects ORDER BY email";
$rows = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
    
    $to[] = $row['email'];
}

$size = sizeof($id);
//echo "<br>Number of channel Ids: ".$size."<br><br>";

// Looping each Url for Each Email to get Data 

foreach($to as $t){
    echo $t."<br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/$id[$i]";
        // echo $url."<br>";

        $channel = trim(explode('https://www.youtube.com/channel/', $url)[1]);
        // echo $channel."<br>";
    
        $rss = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=$channel";
        // echo $rss."<br>";
        
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($rss);    

        $title = $xml->title;
        // echo $title."<br>";
            
        $videoTitle = $xml->entry[0]->title;
        // echo $videoTitle."<br>";
        $id[$i] = $xml->id;
        // echo $id[$i]."<br>";   
        // $idOnly = substr($id[$i] , strpos($id[$i] , "yt:channel:") + 11);    
        // echo $idOnly."<br>";

        $pub[$i] = $xml->entry[0]->published;
        // echo $pub[$i]."<br>";
        $realDate_ = new DateTime($pub[$i]);
        // var_dump($realDate_);
        $realDate2_ = $realDate_->format("D, d M Y")."<br>";
        //echo $realDate2_;    

        $today_ = new DateTime();
        //     $today2_ = $today_->format("D, d M Y")."<br>";
        // echo $today2_;
        // if ($today2_ == $realDate2_) {
        // echo "true";

        // This is the Result with Every Email

        echo $content = "• <a href='https://bladingflix.com/render.php?email=$t&channel=$idOnly'>".$title." - ".$videoTitle."</a><br>";
        // }
    }
}
?>
```

For the First Email the Data Shows Properly but in for the others

Purpose = get collected links add the user email to each url repeat for each.

Comment: If you could remove extraneous commented out code and extra line breaks, format so it is visually easy to follow and show both the expected result as well as the actual result, you'd probably get better help for this

Comment: i tried but didn't get it

Comment: Isn't `$channel` the same as `id[$i]`? Why do you need that `explode()` call?

Comment: you obviously know how to use `foreach` -- why don't you use it with the `$id` array?

Comment: What does "but in for the others" mean? Did you mean "but not for the others"?

Comment: What is `$idOnly`?

Comment: You're modifying the `$id` array in the loop: `$id[$i] = $xml->id;`. For the next email, `$id[$i]` is not a valid channel ID.

Comment: So what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make below changes in your existing code

In the second for() loop you are replacing the `$id` array as below

```php
$id[$i] = $xml->id;
```

Instead of replacing the `$id[$i]` value, create new variable as below

```php
$xmlId = $xml->id;
$idOnly = substr($xmlId, strpos($xmlId , "yt:channel:") + 11);
```

And please uncomment the `$idOnly` variable.
It will work. And try to refactor this code.